# Extra space added at the end of the last word

Tags: c, stdio

Here's my code. It's supposed to write down every second word, starting from START to STOP, from one file to another. The code works fine, but there is an extra space at the end of the last word. Any suggestions? I tried some things but ended up only with extra space in front, no spaces whatsoever, or multiple unwanted spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 100

typedef struct {
    FILE *inputFile;
    FILE *outputFile;
} FilePair;

void initializeFiles(FilePair *files, char *inputFileName, char *outputFileName);
void closeFiles(FilePair *files);
void processFile(FilePair *files);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FilePair files;

    initializeFiles(&files, argv[1], argv[2]);

    if (files.inputFile == NULL || files.outputFile == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    processFile(&files);

    closeFiles(&files);

    return 0;
}

void initializeFiles(FilePair *files, char *inputFileName, char *outputFileName) {
    files->inputFile = fopen(inputFileName, "r");
    files->outputFile = fopen(outputFileName, "w");

    if (files->inputFile == NULL || files->outputFile == NULL) {
        char error[] = "Error opening files\n";
        for (int i = 0; error[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            fputc(error[i], files->outputFile);
        }
        fclose(files->outputFile);
        files->outputFile = NULL; 
        fclose(files->inputFile);
        files->inputFile = NULL; 
        return;
    }
}

void closeFiles(FilePair *files) {
    if (files->inputFile != NULL) {
        fclose(files->inputFile);
        files->inputFile = NULL;
    }
    if (files->outputFile != NULL) {
        fclose(files->outputFile);
        files->outputFile = NULL;
    }
}

void processFile(FilePair *files) {
    char startMarker[7] = "START ";
    char stopMarker[5] = "STOP";
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int startIdx = 0, stopIdx = 0;
    int isStart = 0;
    int spaceCount = 0;

    while (1) {
        int character = fgetc(files->inputFile);
        if (character == EOF) {
            break;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
            buffer[i] = '\0';
        }

        buffer[0] = character;
        for (int i = 1; i < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1; i++) {
            character = fgetc(files->inputFile);
            if (character == EOF || character == '\n') {
                break;
            }
            buffer[i] = character;
        }

        for (int i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            char ch = buffer[i];

            if (isStart) {
                if (spaceCount % 2 != 0) {
                    fputc(ch, files->outputFile);
                }
                if (ch == ' ') {
                    spaceCount++;
                }

                if (ch == stopMarker[stopIdx]) {
                    stopIdx++;
                } else {
                    stopIdx = 0;
                }
                if (stopMarker[stopIdx] == '\0') {
                    isStart = 0;
                }
            } else {
                if (ch == startMarker[startIdx]) {
                    startIdx++;
                } else {
                    startIdx = 0;
                }
                if (startMarker[startIdx] == '\0') {
                    isStart = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was only expecting to remove the space at the end of the last word

Comment: Please provide sample data & expected results.

Comment: OT: How do you expect `fputc(error[i], files->outputFile)` to work if `files->outputFile` is `NULL`?

Comment: As for your problem, please see [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Output the first word without a space. Then output a space before any other word. Don't output a space after any word.

Answer (score 1):

You can slightly modify your logic to remove the extra space at the end of the last word. One way to achieve this is to maintain a flag to check whether the current word is the last one.

**Here's the modified code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 100

typedef struct {
    FILE *inputFile;
    FILE *outputFile;
} FilePair;

void initializeFiles(FilePair *files, char *inputFileName, char *outputFileName);
void closeFiles(FilePair *files);
void processFile(FilePair *files);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FilePair files;

    initializeFiles(&files, argv[1], argv[2]);

    if (files.inputFile == NULL || files.outputFile == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    processFile(&files);

    closeFiles(&files);

    return 0;
}

void initializeFiles(FilePair *files, char *inputFileName, char *outputFileName) {
    files->inputFile = fopen(inputFileName, "r");
    files->outputFile = fopen(outputFileName, "w");

    if (files->inputFile == NULL || files->outputFile == NULL) {
        char error[] = "Error opening files\n";
        for (int i = 0; error[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            fputc(error[i], files->outputFile);
        }
        fclose(files->outputFile);
        files->outputFile = NULL;
        fclose(files->inputFile);
        files->inputFile = NULL;
        return;
    }
}

void closeFiles(FilePair *files) {
    if (files->inputFile != NULL) {
        fclose(files->inputFile);
        files->inputFile = NULL;
    }
    if (files->outputFile != NULL) {
        fclose(files->outputFile);
        files->outputFile = NULL;
    }
}

void processFile(FilePair *files) {
    char startMarker[7] = "START ";
    char stopMarker[5] = "STOP";
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int startIdx = 0, stopIdx = 0;
    int isStart = 0;
    int spaceCount = 0;
    int lastWord = 0;

    while (1) {
        int character = fgetc(files->inputFile);
        if (character == EOF) {
            break;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
            buffer[i] = '\0';
        }

        buffer[0] = character;
        for (int i = 1; i < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1; i++) {
            character = fgetc(files->inputFile);
            if (character == EOF || character == '\n') {
                lastWord = 1;  // Mark that this is the last word
                break;
            }
            buffer[i] = character;
        }

        for (int i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            char ch = buffer[i];

            if (isStart) {
                if (spaceCount % 2 != 0) {
                    fputc(ch, files->outputFile);
                }
                if (ch == ' ') {
                    spaceCount++;
                }

                if (ch == stopMarker[stopIdx]) {
                    stopIdx++;
                } else {
                    stopIdx = 0;
                }
                if (stopMarker[stopIdx] == '\0') {
                    isStart = 0;
                }
            } else {
                if (ch == startMarker[startIdx]) {
                    startIdx++;
                } else {
                    startIdx = 0;
                }
                if (startMarker[startIdx] == '\0') {
                    isStart = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        if (lastWord) {
            // Check if this is the last word and avoid adding an extra space
            fputc('\n', files->outputFile);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The `lastWord` variable is introduced to keep track of whether the current word is the last one. If it is the last word, it avoids adding an extra space at the end. Additionally, it adds a newline character to the output file to maintain a clean output. I hope this helps resolve your bug. For more assistance, you can comment below.

Comment: I was wondering where [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77656812/4581301) was going to turn up.

Comment: Oh sorry, like I typed in the wrong answer window; like both, the tabs were open on my browser. Sorry for the mixup. I hope I haven't offended anyone.

Comment: Nope. No offence. I'd written a comment to let you know the answer had wound up at the wrong question but you deleted it before I could post.

Comment: But the server... It never forgets. It'll add the zero-scored (thus poorly received) answer in, deleted or not, when computing whether or not your account is in good standing. if the server slaps you with an answer ban later, raise a ticket with the community mangers to get the post disassociated with your account. They're usually good about that sort of thing.